# Autosize only Merged Cells using Aspose

Tags: excel, aspose-cells

I saw that there was a way to autofit rows in the worksheet. But I only want to autofit the rows that have only merged cells in it. And keep all of the other rows the same. Not sure if there is a way to do this.

I've tried this but it autofits all rows.

```
AutoFitterOptions options = new AutoFitterOptions();
options.AutoFitMergedCells = true;
_worksheet.AutoFitRows(options);
```

And I won't know the exact row that needs to be autofitted because I'm adding data to the excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following sample code for your needs:

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```cs
Workbook wb = new Workbook("e:\\test2\\Book1.xlsx");
Worksheet _worksheet = wb.Worksheets[0];
var cells = _worksheet.Cells;
foreach (Cell cell in cells)
{
   if (cell.IsMerged)
   {
        int row = cell.Row;
        AutoFitterOptions options = new AutoFitterOptions();
        options.AutoFitMergedCells = true;
        _worksheet.AutoFitRows(row, row, options);
   }
}

wb.Save("e:\\test2\\out1.xlsx");
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

You may also post your queries in dedicated [forums](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.